# windows django AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split

Tags: windows, django

I am using the following command on WinXP and getting an error, but works fine on MacOS and Linux, thank you very very much for any help.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Sites\team_track>manage.py syncdb --settings=local_settings
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table app_player
Creating table app_team_players
Creating table app_team
Creating table app_game
Creating table app_gameparticipant

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (Leave blank to use 'administrator'):
E-mail address: kam@kam.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Sites\team_track\manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_manager(team_tracker.settings)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_mana
ger
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 121, in handl
e_noargs
    custom_sql = custom_sql_for_model(model, self.style, connection)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 166, in custom_sql_for_mo
del
    backend_name = connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'].split('.')[-1]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Here is what my manage.py looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os.path

from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import team_tracker.settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(team_tracker.settings)
```

And my local_settings.py resides in root dir:

```
from team_tracker.settings import *

DEBUG = True

#DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
#DATABASE_NAME = 'caktus_website.db'

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = 'team_track.db' # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
```

And finally my team_tracker/settings.py is here:

```
# Django settings for team_tracker project.
import os.path

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MANAGERS = ADMINS

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
#        'NAME': 'team_track.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
#        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
#        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
#        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
#        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
#    }
#}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/kamilski81/Sites/team_tracker/media/'#os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'appmedia')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/kamilski81/Sites/team_tracker/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'v8#s)7gw-^@zp&6**g7rz$uj!@3v4a36so_uw!_#0pa$h4)b-s'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
#  @kamtodo: find out how to truly use this and the best way if we have many forms
#    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'), 
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'app',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `local_settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3',
```

The comma here makes `DATABASE_ENGINE` a tuple with one element instead of a string. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using the separate DATABASE_* settings anyway - you should use the format that you've commented out (why???) in settings.py.